# How to change Tabs using JavaFX by outside event handler?

Tags: events, tabs, javafx, actionlistener

Building an application in which a phone interacts with a PC application. The application (which has a GUI on the PC side) appears as JavaFX Tabbed Pane. I am going to "listen" for a event "A" which comes from the phone. When this event "A" occurs, I would like to change tabs on the tabbed pane (PC side). Is there a way I can implement a listener to overload the existing clickable tabs, so that event "A" can also change between tabs?

I hope this is not overly confusing. I simply want the application to to change panes by a separate event. I don't even know where to start since all the details of the tabbed pane are hidden in the API. Thanks in advance.

Karl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood your question, try

```
public void myEventAHandler() {
    tabPane.getSelectionModel().select(desired_tab_index);
}
```